# Email always takes the `if` and not the `else if`/`else` path

Tags: php, email, if-statement

I have a function in my website where you can buy stuff. After you do that, you will get an email. Everything works fine except for one thing. I have an `if`statement in my code, but it always takes the `if` and not the `else if` or `else` path.

I searched on the Internet but I couldn't find any solution. I tried different things in my `else if` like `else if (isset empty($registrationInfo['serviceselectoptie'])` and `else if (isset ($registrationInfo['serviceselectoptie'] === NULL)` but that didn't work.

**My `if` statement**

```
<?php
  $registrationInfo = $connect->select(
    "SELECT * FROM `registrationinfo` WHERE `orderId`= '".$order_id."' LIMIT 1"
  )->fetch();

  if (
    isset($registrationInfo['serviceselectoptie']) AND 
    isset($registrationInfo['serviceconsult'])
  ) { 
    $titellist = '<tr><td bgcolor="#DEDEDE" style="padding: 5px 5px 5px 5px;width:175px;">' 
      .$registrationInfo['serviceselectoptie'].':</td><td style="padding: 5px 5px 5px 5px;">'
      .$registrationInfo['serviceconsult'] .'</td></tr>'; 
  } else if (
    !isset($registrationInfo['serviceselectoptie']) AND
    isset($registrationInfo['serviceconsult'])
  ) {
    $titellist = '<tr><td bgcolor="#DEDEDE" style="padding: 5px 5px 5px 5px;width:175px;">'
     .'Bestelling:</td><td style="padding: 5px 5px 5px 5px;">'
     .$registrationInfo['serviceconsult'].'</td></tr>';
  } else { 
    $titellist = "";
  }
?>
```

What I expect is that if  the `$registrationInfo['serviceselectoptie']` row is empty (`null`), it will go to the `else if`. My actual output is that it takes the `if` path and because the row is empty it will just give `:`

**Example of output**

[image: example output]

Comment: show us what you got from database, by var_dump for example

Comment: what do you want me to var_dump?

Comment: var_dump($registrationInfo);

Comment: @RomanBobrik how can i do that in an email?

Comment: you can try var_export(), or simply write another piece of code where you are only getting data by order ID, just to check what you have after DB fetch

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As you are checking the details in a result set, you will find that they will always be set, what you may want instead is to check if the value is `empty()`, as you want to make sure there is a value though - you will have to say if `!empty()` to check if it has a value...

```
if(!empty($registrationInfo['serviceselectoptie']) 
      AND !empty($registrationInfo['serviceconsult']))
```

apply this to the other parts of the code as well.

Comment: Should do - from the manual *A variable is considered empty if it does not exist or if its value equals FALSE*

Comment: There's a difference between `NULL` (no value/reference) and empty (`""`), which is why you need the `!empty()` check.

Comment: @NigelRen Thanks mate it works. I checked the wrong page haha sometimes im so dumb

Comment: @NigelRen True it's because i have 3 different languages in my website so i was working on the dutch part and tested the english side haha

Answer (score 0):

`isset($registrationInfo['serviceselectoptie'])` is truthy when `serviceselectoptie` key exists in the array and is set to either an empty string or a value other than `NULL`.

```php
// php -a
// Interactive shell

> $test = ['a'=>2, 'b'=>null, 'c'=>''];

> echo isset($test['a']);
 1
> echo isset($test['b']);
> echo isset($test['c']);
1
```

A better check is using `empty` function.

```php
// php -a
// Interactive shell

> $test = ['a'=>2, 'b'=>null, 'c'=>''];

> echo empty($test['a']);
> echo empty($test['b']);
1
> echo empty($test['c']);
1
> echo empty($test['d']); // non-existent key 
1
> echo empty(NULL['a']); // yes NULL can be indexed
1
```

This way the branches in your code will be as:

```php
if(
    !empty($registrationInfo['serviceselectoptie'])
    AND !empty($registrationInfo['serviceconsult'])) { 
    //... 

} 
else if(
    empty($registrationInfo['serviceselectoptie'])
    AND !empty($registrationInfo['serviceconsult'])) {
    //...
} 
else { 
    //... 
}
```